# Python type hints - how to handle a variable that changes type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am adding type hints to a code base. Part of the code looks like this

```
var1 = get_my_int()      # var1 is an int
...
if var1 !=0:
     var1 = hex(var1)    # var1 is now a string

output = f"something {var1}"
```

[mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) will complain

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
```

The easiest solution is to create a new variable. For example:

```
if var1 !=0:
     output = f"something {var1}"
else:
     var1_hex = hex(var1)              # var1_hex is a string, var1 is an int
     output = f"something {var1_hex}"
```

What is the cleanest solution?

Comment: ideally you shouldn't be reusing variables in that way, otherwise your code will be hard to read

Comment: I would definitely just create a new variable. It may help in debugging later to see what the old value was at the very least. To satisfy the type linter and do literally what you're asking, you could use `var1: str | int = get_my_int()` (`|` == `Union`), but I wouldn't recommend that. Just create a new variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would also convert `0` to a string for the purpose of including in the f-string, so that you can use the same assignment to `output` in both cases.

```
var1_str = hex(var1) if var1 else "0"
output = f'something {var1_str}'
```

This assumes that `"0x0"` isn't suitable for some reason, precluding the simplest solution

```
output = f'something {hex(var1)}'
```

For that matter, you don't strictly need `var1_str` at all:

```
output = f'something {hex(var1) if var1 else "0"}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the first suggestion using the ternary operator is the best.
The mypy flag `--allow-redefinition` allows redefinition as long as the redefinition is at the same indentation level as the declaration.